# XPATH (1.0) query for fetching text until specific tag

Tags: php, html, xpath

I'm building an in-house reader-style PHP app which fetches text from our pages and then does various manipulations on it. The text on most of our HTML pages is unordered so the app has to be able to grab text without using class names or other navigation anchors since there are none. Only the text title is relevant as an anchor.

I would like to fetch text from a given start node (the title) and then stop when I reach an img tag (which may or may not exist, if not then this would mean that all the text should be fetched). I've currently succeeded only in fetching the text without the image using XPath.

Here's a sample HTML

```
<b>Some title</b>
<br/> Important text
<br/> More important text
<p> More text I which should be fetched</p>
<p><img src="foo.jpg"/></p>
<p> Unimportant text, don't want it!</p>
```

This is the XPath query I'm currently using `//*[text()="Some title"]/following::text()`.

The above indeed fetches the relevant text, however I would like it to stop at the img tag if it exists. Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fetch all text nodes that are not preceded by an image.

```
//*[text()="Some title"]/following::text()[not(preceding::img)]
```

You can easily further restrict which images to stop at if needed.